# Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have found a couple of Stackoverflow posts where people have had the same issue but cannot seem to implement the suggested fixes in a satisfactory mannor for python to compile my script.

I understand that it wants self to be passed into database but cannot understand where I am going to get this from as self from my main.py contains the wrong context.

I have my main class in which I want to call the database class and execute a function from within.

main.py

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = Database
        self.db.createConnection()
```

database.py

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
            #some setup here

    def createConnection(self):
            #Create connection code here
```

When I run this, I am presented with the following error.

```
TypeError: createConnection() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: In the class `Main` change `self.db = Database` to `self.db = Database()`

Comment: As if by magic, this worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to assign an instance of `Database` to `self.db`, not assign the `Database` class itself.  Add parentheses to call `Database` and instantiate it:

```
self.db = Database()
```